# jscrollpane that is shorter than its div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, jscrollpane

I have a div with a jscrollpane on it. At the moment the scroll bar is the size of the the div. I.e. if the div is 100 pixel high then the scroll bar is 100 pixel high too. What I want is to have a gap above and below the scroll bar so I can put different buttons their. So if the div is 100 pixel high, perhaps the jscrollpane could be 60 pixel high, with 20 pixel space above and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found you can, for anybody else with this problem here's some great info: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/caps.html